# Use current values as placeholders in form

Tags: php, forms

I am almost done with a complex calculator, but have a minor issue. After the user presses the calculate button, all the values in the fields are removed. I have tried adding the appropriate variable in the placeholder, but when I do that, the placeholder displays the value that I set as default when I initialized it. I assume this is happening because the calculate button is forcing the page to refresh. What are my options here to keep the updated values in the fields.

Also ... for my future reference...is php not the way to go in this circumstance? Would java or html have been better choices?

My code can be viewed here: https://github.com/DTAngie/LearningProjects/blob/master/ComplexCalc

and you can view the result at: http://distechs.com/development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"<?php echo $annlAvgFranchisees; ?>"><?php if(isset($_POST['calculate'])) {
        $annlAvgFranchisees = $_POST['Annl-avg-franchisees'];
    } ?>
```

You write your variable before it set.

How about

```
 if(isset($_POST['calculate'])) {
            Echo  $_POST['Annl-avg-franchisees']; } else { echo $annlAvgFranchisees;}
```

Or you can make it shorter with ternarry

```
Echo (isset($_POST['calculate'])) ? $_POST['Annl-avg-franchisees']  : $annlAvgFranchisees;)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of achieving what you want would be get the inputs from $_POST and assigning them to your default variables after their initialization (if they are set on $_POST set).

That way, on the first user interaction on the page, your default variables would fill the placeholders. After the post call, the page is reloaded and your code would assign the variables (if set) to the placeholders.